# SharePoint 2013 workflow general question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow

Want to know after create the workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 for Custom List (OOTB) in SharePoint 2013, once I save and publish the workflow in SharePoint Designer it will start working for my List or I have to do some setting in SharePoint List also from ribbon. The reason I'm asking this question because I've created one workflow in SharePoint Designer, Save and then publish it. After save the workflow one new column is created in my List but the workflow is not doing any action as per expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in designer go to your workflow settings.

You should see a Start Options.
The default is set to "Allow this workflow to be manually started"

If you want the workflow to start as soon as the item is created or edited. select the appropriate check box.

- "Start workflow automatically when an item is created"
- "Start workflow automatically when an item is Changed"

To start the workflow manually you can go to the view properties of the list item and then click on workflow in the ribbon.
There you should see the name of the workflow that you published.